# How to replace the title (or alt) of each image by its following figcaption text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm new in jQuery and I'm fighting with that piece of code since hours now.
I know I'm close to the answer but got stuck... Could you help me please? :-)

Here the architecture :

```
<figure id="01">
  <a><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
  <figcaption>Text I want to copy</figcaption>
</figure>    

<figure id="02">
  <a><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
  <figcaption>A different text I want to copy</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure id="03">
  <a><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
  <figcaption>Another text I want to copy</figcaption>
</figure>

etc...
```

I'd like to fill the **title or alt tag image** (actually empty) with the text of the figcaption for each figure.

```
$("figure a img").each(function() {
    var captiontext = $(this).parent().parent('figcaption').text();
    $(this).prop("title", captiontext);
});
```

Live test here: http://jsfiddle.net/y08d4mq9/7/

Any idea ?

Comment: `$(this).parent().next('figcaption').text()` as `figcaption` is a sibling of `a`, not its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this JS code:

```
$("figure").each(function(){
    var captiontext = $(this).find("figcaption").text();
    $(this).find("img").attr("alt", captiontext);
});
```

You may also have a look on [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2n5u5x3t/), demonstrating the procedure.

Comment: Thank Daniel, this is working as well and it's a bit more clear for me than the "one line solution" of Cattla, Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("figure").each(function() {
   $(this).find('img').attr('alt',$(this).children('figcaption').text());
});
```

[**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqpsydL5/2/)